# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'users' since it isn't a known property of 'app-user'

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando consumir os dados de uma api teste baseada em Laravel, mas estou  obtendo o seguinte erro:

```
Can't bind to 'users' since it isn't a known property of 'app-user'.
```

USERCOMPONENT

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { User} from './user';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
@Component({
selector: 'app-user',
   templateUrl: './user.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
   users: User[]
constructor(private userService: UserService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
   this.listarUsuarios();
}
   listarUsuarios(): void{
   this.userService.listaUsararios().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
}
}
```

USERSERVICE

```js
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { User } from "./user";
const API = 'http://localhost:8000/api/user/users';
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
   export class UserService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   }

   listaUsararios(): Observable<User[]> {
      return this.http.get<User[]>(API);
   }
}
```

USERMODULE

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';


import { UserComponent} from './user.component';
import { UserServices } from './user.services';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule

  ],
  exports:[
    UserComponent,
  ],

  providers:[ 
   UserServices
  ]
})

export class UserModule { }
```

USERINTERFACE

```js
export interface User {
   id: number,
   name:string,
   email: string,
   telefone:string
   datascimento: Date,
}
```

APP.COMPONENT.HTML

```html
<app-home></app-home>
<app-user></app-user>
```

Alguém sabia me ajudar nessa situação, estou iniciando no Angular.

Comment: no user module, seu import do user service parece estar diferente. Essa linha aqui está correta? import { UserServices } from './userServices';

Comment: Não era isso...infelizmente o erro permanece o mesmo

Comment: normalmente isso se da porque vc esta usando algum input tipo <app-users [users]="users"></app-users> 
Mas no seu caso não vejo por que daria esse erro. Em que momento vc acessa o users?

Comment: Tenta inicializar o user `users: User[] = []` - Acredito que não seja isso, mas vamos tentar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man , pra fazer o data-bind precisa adicionar o decorator @Input no arquivo user.component.ts antes da variável user, e também importar do angular/core, assim o angular entende que é uma variável de entrada.

```
   import { Input } from '@angular/core'
   import { User } from 'user-interface'

   @Input() user:User
```